# Cannot grant to private chat rooms

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, error-message

I just created a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1133/room-for-gilles-and-michael-mrozek), made it private, and tried to grant access to another user. This doesn't seem to be possible:

- In the “requested access” list, if I select any of the four settings on the per-user dropdown (be it “no special access”, “read access”, “write access” or “owner”) then click “change”, I'm brought to a [Page not found](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/setuseraccess/1133).
- Same thing if I click on “add a user” in the “explicit read access” or “explicit write access” or “owners” section and enter the user's name or chat user ID then click “grant read access”/“grant write access”/“make owner”.

Comment: By the way, Michael can now access the room because I've associated it with the site where he's a moderator. But the bug stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens only on rooms that were created with either the "start a new room with this user" or the "move the comment discussion to chat" functions. Fixed after the next chat build.